# Assign dbo role to login without creating a new user in db

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to create assign dbo rights on an existing database to an existing login without creating a new user in the database. I would like to have the login use dbo user, like a member of sa server role does.

All I have found involves creating a new db user.

Thanks!

Comment: `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'your user'`. Note that [sp_addrolemember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) is announced as to be deprecated as of sql server 2014.

Comment: That adds a db user to a role. I want to alias an existing user from a login

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to avoid `CREATE USER foo FROM LOGIN foo;`?

Comment: @Metaphor do you mean that you want to use the old `sp_addalias` similiar in SQL Server 2014 ? e.g. `sp_addalias 'your_login','dbo'` is same as doing `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'your login'` - provided the login exists and is having a schema of `dbo` as default. Also its much easy as Aaron mentioned above to create a user and then grant it a dbowner or whatever permission you want.

Comment: My problem is that we are deploying dacpacs that really don't like seeing users in the target database that aren't in the dacpac. Thanks for sp_addalias, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I guess "old" means that it doesn't exist any longer. "Login exists and is having a schema of dbo as default" can you elaborate? Or maybe make it an answer.

Comment: No, "old" means it will stop working. See this note in [the SQL Server **2005** documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184394(v=sql.90).aspx): `This feature will be removed in the next version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.`

Comment: Also, what does "doesn't like" mean? If you need database users to support your application, why can't they exist in your code / dacpacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, this should be fixed from the deployment side of things and not from a questionable modification of the target database side of things (referring to the conversation in the comments on the Question related to using the deprecated `sp_addalias`).

Depending on what the exact problem is, there are various configuration options of DacPac deployment that can be used to get around such conflicts. These options can either be specified on the command line if running [SqlPackage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080.aspx), or can be placed into a DAC Publish Profile (i.e. an XML config file).

The options of interest here are listed in the [Publish Parameters, Properties, and SQLCMD Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080.aspx#Anchor_5) section of the `SqlPackage` page.

To start with, do you have any of the following set to `True`:

- `DropObjectsNotInSource` (default: False)
- `DropRoleMembersNotInSource` (default: False)
- `IgnoreLoginSids` (default: True)

If you have the `DropObjectsNotInSource` property set to `True`, then try adding:

- `DoNotDropObjectType=Users`
- `ExcludeObjectType=Users`
- `IgnoreRoleMembership=True`
- `IgnoreUserSettingsObjects=True` ??

If needing to specify the `ExcludeObjectType` property, that would look as follows, depending on where it is specified:

- On the command-line: `/p:ExcludeObjectType=Users`
- In a DAC Publish Profile:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project ToolsVersion="12.0"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
          <ExcludeObjectType>Users</ExcludeObjectType>
      </PropertyGroup>
  </Project>
  ```

Comment: This information is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Metaphor No problem. Does that mean that one or more of these options solved the issue? If so, which one(s)? It would help to have it documented.

Comment: @Metaphor Also, next time you ask a question, please consider giving more backgroup on it. If it weren't for the discussion in the comments mentioning DacPacs, I would not have posted this answer. It would have helped if the question started with, "I am trying to deploy DacPacs but am running into a problem with Users that exist in the target database but not in the DacPac". Just FYI :-).

Comment: will do. I wasn't looking for a deployment solution though, we have different teams doing dev, db and deployment. I was originally just looking for an equivalent of sp_addalias. DoNotDropObjectType=Users will work with the help of the deployment team. I'll have to do batch files for the devs to deploy local dbs.

Comment: @Metaphor I understand the separation of teams part, but this really is a deployment issue. And the "alias" concept seems to be going away. But just to mention this, the `dbo` User that is in each database can be reassigned to a different login: it doesn't need to be associated with `sa`. But it can only be assigned to one Login at a time since it is an actual User, not a role. I don't know if that would help any, and I am not even sure that I would recommend it, but there ya go :-). Do you have Users that are in the DacPac? If not, you should try the `IgnoreType=Users` instead maybe?

Comment: thanks again. We do not put users in the dacpacs. I'll give the IgnoreType a go.